# Proper LogoutRequest for Single Logout with ADFS IdP

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, adfs, onelogin

I'm successfully using OneLogin java-saml library for SAML SSO. But there are problems with SLO (Single Logout) with Active Directory Federation Service (ADFS). LogoutRequest created by the library is rejected by ADFS, while it is accepted by SimpleSAMLphp IdP. I pass both `nameId` and `sessionIndex` received from ADFS in Response at LogoutRequest creation.

Here are generated requests and received responses:

AuthNRequest:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="ONELOGIN_a80567d6-8957-482b-90e9-99d1b40ec8b1" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-05-31T15:43:07Z" ProviderName="My Company Service Provider" Destination="https://wintest.mycompany.test/adfs/ls/" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://localhost:8443/builder/login_check_sso">
   <saml:Issuer>http://localhost:4568/sso/saml/metadata</saml:Issuer>
   <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" AllowCreate="true" />
   <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
      <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
   </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Response:

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" Destination="https://localhost:8443/builder/login_check_sso" ID="_f5ea3a59-92f9-4b22-aaf0-36ed392df051" InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_a80567d6-8957-482b-90e9-99d1b40ec8b1" IssueInstant="2017-05-31T15:43:10.158Z" Version="2.0">
   <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://wintest.mycompany.test/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
   <samlp:Status>
      <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
   </samlp:Status>
   <Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_6f6daef8-f0b5-4437-8e35-ae44ffc48cfe" IssueInstant="2017-05-31T15:43:10.158Z" Version="2.0">
      <Issuer>http://wintest.mycompany.test/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
         <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#_6f6daef8-f0b5-4437-8e35-ae44ffc48cfe">
               <ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
               </ds:Transforms>
               <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
               <ds:DigestValue>FNwbMonYZBBvTXSRbCWP7WxZgPZPSCcCFZozok9eRK4=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
         </ds:SignedInfo>
         <ds:SignatureValue>fG1SIq3azZfBFQ+5YBBruuCQ03sLIHJ/YpK/AAOYkyJKXEZ5+SvNLgl+8/3a6Tk8mabZmwmawoJRf5UPb+fNtk+CeeWJ7kiUYcb2uvB4ic7Qd4qB+OgfqK0qVCkn9FWGEODLXA6v4tXWBZfSnzDrHEg7xLHrngesSnffY3uyQvH/rm4G2Vjd59LUeUtpJo2X5ZjVuk4sT5r21+UxpNU9LX8z7hXAZHhD1o4d2dqAs21tAGoid3p0RgNDy1WWGh1WSjFLHPDh220ZIchRFKveJE3R9M9nTKtOFESQsYc6TfmhJ5+Xm/j0VY7vvdhgguyq4MKzcPFK6tBL7I8KREck/Q==</ds:SignatureValue>
         <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
               <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
         </KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <Subject>
         <NameID>hamilton1@mycompany.test</NameID>
         <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_a80567d6-8957-482b-90e9-99d1b40ec8b1" NotOnOrAfter="2017-05-31T15:48:10.158Z" Recipient="https://localhost:8443/builder/login_check_sso" />
         </SubjectConfirmation>
      </Subject>
      <Conditions NotBefore="2017-05-31T15:43:10.158Z" NotOnOrAfter="2017-05-31T16:43:10.158Z">
         <AudienceRestriction>
            <Audience>http://localhost:4568/sso/saml/metadata</Audience>
         </AudienceRestriction>
      </Conditions>
      <AttributeStatement>
         <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
            <AttributeValue>hamilton@mycompany.com</AttributeValue>
         </Attribute>
      </AttributeStatement>
      <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2017-05-31T12:18:50.194Z" SessionIndex="_6f6daef8-f0b5-4437-8e35-ae44ffc48cfe">
         <AuthnContext>
            <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef>
         </AuthnContext>
      </AuthnStatement>
   </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

LogoutRequest:

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="ONELOGIN_947f5e64-8423-4464-b4b0-fa416dfe62a0" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-05-31T15:43:18Z" Destination="https://wintest.mycompany.test/adfs/ls/">
   <saml:Issuer>http://localhost:4568/sso/saml/metadata</saml:Issuer>
   <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">hamilton1@mycompany.test</saml:NameID>
   <samlp:SessionIndex>_6f6daef8-f0b5-4437-8e35-ae44ffc48cfe</samlp:SessionIndex>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

LogoutResponse:

```
<samlp:LogoutResponse xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="_1b3e8c81-2aba-45be-8fe6-54edda514d51" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-05-31T15:43:24.808Z" Destination="https://localhost:8443/builder/logout_sso" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_947f5e64-8423-4464-b4b0-fa416dfe62a0">
   <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://wintest.mycompany.test/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
   <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
         <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
         <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
         <ds:Reference URI="#_1b3e8c81-2aba-45be-8fe6-54edda514d51">
            <ds:Transforms>
               <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
               <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <ds:DigestValue>NDfLVWPkh2/UCEbLQ6V97OK2u4pajv3aLB9cPs5JkSc=</ds:DigestValue>
         </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue>M1JaIz/AeJAh1bUzAUBrljch9EVOVA6K3lzuFDWwF0LtmXgcMEZV9Htp9owq5MNcOZ/mymBrKmndz1EDwDxwOCLjpvp5QX42G23dUCyYAGfQXE1Dzub7dsaTSlMWnkbh6fMLk/j5/fcLEi8vwXMInQv6isVpxnbYI+4ayQWOzo9QpfJBaromDDqVwbmkoT8lhRo06n32OAi8CtaAS2rjNqJyPfcnLp3jMpfg5Qh3wiKYnT6VkMpXw5ddVASByKlqzIRiuItwJsqF4JDDj+f2qgSdq6PaTgYpu8xnbFXTdOvDeg0ZgetQrnaZ07+5xLFLGI73feAWPUFPXwMHQ2THXA==</ds:SignatureValue>
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
         <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
         </ds:X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
   </ds:Signature>
   <samlp:Status>
      <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester" />
   </samlp:Status>
</samlp:LogoutResponse>
```

The error appeared on ADFS is: `The SAML Single Logout request does not correspond to the logged-in session participant.` With extra error description:

```
User Action 
Verify that the claim provider trust or the relying party trust configuration is up to date. If the name identifier in the request is different from the name identifier in the session only by NameQualifier or SPNameQualifier, check and correct the name identifier policy issuance rule using the AD FS Management snap-in.
```

What should be modified in LogoutRequest to make logout happen?

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your issue but should the NameID format in the Logout request be SAML:2.0 instead of SAML:1.1 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, the problem is solved.

As you can see in SAML Response I've posted `NameID` element doesn't have `Format` attribute:

```
<Subject>
     <NameID>hamilton1@mycompany.test</NameID>
     ...
</Subject>
```

So ADFS expects that Format attribute will be absent in `LogouRequest` too.
The following LogoutRequests results in successful logout:

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="ONELOGIN_947f5e64-8423-4464-b4b0-fa416dfe62a0" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-05-31T15:43:18Z" Destination="https://wintest.mycompany.test/adfs/ls/">
   <saml:Issuer>http://localhost:4568/sso/saml/metadata</saml:Issuer>
   <saml:NameID>hamilton1@mycompany.test</saml:NameID>
   <samlp:SessionIndex>_6f6daef8-f0b5-4437-8e35-ae44ffc48cfe</samlp:SessionIndex>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

If I change Claim Issuing Policy to map Name ID to EmailAddress in ADFS with the following rules:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"), query = ";mail;{0}", param = c.Value);

c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress");
```

I receive the following SAML Response:

```
<Subject>
     <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:emailAddress">hamilton1@mycompany.test</NameID>
     ...
</Subject>
```

And sending `LogutRequest` with `<NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:emailAddress">` logout happens successfully:

I'm using java-saml of version 2.0.1, so I'm doing the following in Java because `LogoutRequest` doesn't have a constructor accepting `nameIdFormat`: https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/blob/v2.0.1/core/src/main/java/com/onelogin/saml2/logout/LogoutRequest.java:

```
LogoutRequest logoutRequest = new LogoutRequest(settings, null, nameId, sessionIndex);
String samlRequestXml = logoutRequest.getLogoutRequestXml();
samlRequestXml = samlRequestXml.replaceAll(" Format=\".+\"", "");
```

There plans to add `LogoutRequest` constructor accepting `nameIdFormat` as an argument. More details in https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/issues/98.